# H2 how to set column-organized to ANALYTICS

Tags: sql, db2, h2

We have a DB2 instance which is set the DB2_WORKLOAD registry variable to ANALYTICS (read about this [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc/doc/c0060592.html))
Which means that all tables are organized by row:

Here is a small example:

```
CREATE TABLE ERRORS (
                ID BIGINT NOT NULL, 
                MESSAGE VARCHAR(255), 
                STACK CLOB(64000), 
                CAUSE VARCHAR(255), 
                PRIMARY KEY (ID)) ORGANIZE BY ROW;
```

When I am trying to execute the same SQL on H2 I get error ( `Syntax error in SQL statement` )

Is it possible to have DB2 compatibility mode for ANALYTICS?

Comment: When DB2_WORKLOAD is set to ANALYTICS tables are organized by COLUMN by default. You can override that as shown and tell DB2 to organize by ROW. Your error is with H2?

Comment: Yes, my error is with H2.